# Apply expanding window on subsections of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, windowing

I have a dataframe like this

```
  key1  day  feat
0    a    1  None
1    a    2     A
2    a    3  None
3    a    4     A
4    b    1     A
5    b    2  None
6    b    3  None
7    b    4     A
```

I would like the apply an expanding window with the count function over the feat column but apply the expanding window by sub category based on the key1 column.

eg I want my resultant df to be

```
  key1  day  feat count
0    a    1  None   0
1    a    2     A   1
2    a    3  None   1
3    a    4     A   2
4    b    1     A   1
5    b    2  None   1
6    b    3  None   1
7    b    4     A   2
```

So in this case I would be grouping by key1 and then apply the expanding window to the sub groups so that the count resets for each group.
Note that in my actual problem, there are two keys I need to group by not just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets do `groupby` + `cumsum`

```
df['feat'] = df['feat'].replace('None', np.nan) # use only if None is a string
df['count'] = df['feat'].notna().groupby(df['key1']).cumsum()
```

Result

```
  key1  day feat  count
0    a    1  NaN      0
1    a    2    A      1
2    a    3  NaN      1
3    a    4    A      2
4    b    1    A      1
5    b    2  NaN      1
6    b    3  NaN      1
7    b    4    A      2
```

Comment: This doesn't fill the rows inbetween, it only applies the cumulative value to the non nan values. I'm looking for the '1' to be persisted on every row until the next count and so on. Otherwise it works how I want

Comment: This matches the outcome you provided in your question, no?

Comment: Using your solution and adding `.ffil()' to the end solved it